# Changing a wordpress woo commerce category permalink to be way shorter and pretty.

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, woocommerce, permalinks

I am building a site and i need the PermaLinks to specific categories to be very short so the artist has a small share link. My site it Kijis.com

Here is the current structure to get to an artist category 
/product-category/artist/paris-blohm/

Im looking to make it as close to this as possible. 
/paris-blohm/

I have tried a few ways in the wordpress permalinks section to no avail. i have search around a bit and haven't found anything either due to the compoundness of the problem.. i need a human to answer this. I think its going to have somthing to do with modRewrite or .htaccess

for additional information. I am using woo commerce and here is the original theme. 
http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Anyone able to figure this out??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a manual redirect in .htaccess file.  If you have many artists needing a short/pretty URL, that method would become a bit cumbersome, however.

Adding the following to your .htaccess file should produce the result from your example:

Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^paris-blohm.*$ http://domain.com/product-category/artist/paris-blohm/ [R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks so much man!

I added that to my .htaccess but its not doing exactly what i need. when i go to http://kijis.com/paris-blohm/ it forwards me to /product/paris-blohm-tee-alchemy-flame/ not the category but a specific product.

Comment: what is the final URL of your category page?  If you will post that block of your htaccess I will see if I can help further

Comment: Thanks man. @jdm2112 

Here it is http://kijis.com/product-category/artist/paris-blohm/

Artist is a category, and Paris Blohm is a sub category. Ideally i want domain/Paris-Blohm to be it but i will settle for domain/artist/Paris-Blohm